# Slider in renderui not working

Tags: shiny

I have a shiny app that:

- starts with a Leaflet with some points on it
- allows the user to load a CSV using fileInput
- plots the CSV on the map with LeafletProxy
- adds dynamically a slider to filter values from the new CSV

My problem is that the slider doesn't have any effect on the map. It displays fine, but when I move it, neither observe nor observeevent has an effect.

The relevant parts of my code are

```
  # Create a new map with the data uploaded
  observe({
    if (is.null(newdata())) return(NULL)
    # Update the map
    leafletProxy("map", data = newdata()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addCircles(newdata()$Y,
                 newdata()$X,
                 color = "red")
    # Add a slider
    datecol <- newdata()$Date
    output$setSlider <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(newdata())) return(NULL)
      sliderInput("range", "Dates",
                  min = as.Date(min(datecol)),
                  max = as.Date(max(datecol)),#,"%Y-%m-%d"
                  value = c(as.Date(min(datecol)),as.Date(max(datecol))),
                  timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d")
    })
  })

  # Filter the data
  dataloc <- reactive({
    print(input$range)
    filteredData <- newdata()
    if(!is.null(input$range)){
      filteredData <- filteredData %>%
        filter(filteredData$Date >= input$range[1],
               filteredData$Date <= input$range[2])
    }
    return(filteredData)
  })

  observeEvent(input$range,{
    filterloc <- dataloc()
    print("event")
    if (is.null(newdata())) return(NULL)
    if (!is.null(dataloc())) return(print(dataloc()))
      # Update the map
      leafletProxy("map", data = dataloc()) %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        addCircles(dataloc()$Y,
                   dataloc()$X,
                   color = "red")
    }
  )
```

The `print("event")` doesn't happen after the slider has appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had a "submitButton" which prevented the other events to happen. Problem solved!